# Unresolved external symbol when using vkSetDebugUtilsObjectNameEXT()?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, vulkan, unresolved-external

Well i have changed some old function and after closing the Validationlayers tell me that i dont delete/clear up recources and now trying to set up DebugUtilsObjectName function to make it easier to find the recource;

```cpp
void DebugUtilsObjectName(uint64_t objectHandle, const char* pObjectName, VkDevice device, VkObjectType objectType) {
    VkDebugUtilsObjectNameInfoEXT DebugUtilsObjectNameInfo{};
    DebugUtilsObjectNameInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_OBJECT_NAME_INFO_EXT;
    DebugUtilsObjectNameInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    DebugUtilsObjectNameInfo.objectType = objectType;
    DebugUtilsObjectNameInfo.objectHandle = objectHandle;
    DebugUtilsObjectNameInfo.pObjectName = pObjectName;

    vkSetDebugUtilsObjectNameEXT(device, &DebugUtilsObjectNameInfo);
}
```

and i end up with:

[image: Linker error i end up with:]

I tried reading through the doc of it and couldn't find anything outstanding that might help me

Comment: This is an extension so you must load this function at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vulkan headers only expose prototypes for extension functions, provided you did not add `VK_NO_PROTOTYPES`. It does not provide actual functions. This is to allow you to override things like `VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE` or `VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES` (in which case [you also need to load core functions manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791051/overriding-vk-use-64-bit-ptr-defines)).

You must load extension function pointers manually using `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` for instance function pointers or `vkGetDeviceProcAddr` for device function pointers (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504545/vulkan-difference-between-vkgetinstanceprocaddress-and-vkgetdeviceprocaddress) for the differences):

```cpp
auto* pfn = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkSetDebugUtilsObjectNameEXT>(vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkSetDebugUtilsObjectNameEXT"));
```

You may also extract that stuff from `vulkan.hpp` which has [a list of symbols to load](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/c8cf030fe9a00493ff854910000c23ab645cc490/vulkan/vulkan.hpp#L15411) or consider [`VOLK`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader) (I think ?).